# Integral of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$

Tags: integration

So I have to do the integration of $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$. Give me a hint. What should I replace? Should I do it with integration by parts?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: substitute $x = \tan{y}$; $dx = \sec^2{y} dy$.  Then $x^2+1 = \sec^2{y}$.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the substitution
$$
\begin{align}
&&u&=x+\sqrt{x^2+1},&x&=\frac{u^2-1}{2u} \\
&&\sqrt{x^2+1}&=\frac{u^2+1}{2u},&dx&=\frac{u^2+1}{2u^2}du
\end{align}
$$
to get (unless I did some mistake)
$$
\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}dx=
\int\frac{\frac{u^2+1}{2u}}{\frac{u^2-1}{2u}}\frac{u^2+1}{2u^2}du=
\int\frac{(u^2+1)^2}{2u^2(u^2-1)}du=
\int\frac{(u^2-1)^2+4u^2}{2u^2(u^2-1)}du=
$$
$$
=\int\left(\frac{(u^2-1)^2}{2u^2(u^2-1)}+\frac{4u^2}{2u^2(u^2-1)}\right)\,du=
\int\left(\frac{u^2-1}{2u^2}+\frac{2}{u^2-1}\right)\,du=
$$
$$
=\frac{u}{2}+\frac{1}{2u}+\ln|u-1|-\ln|u+1|+C.
$$
Now just do the backsubstitution.

Comment: Interesting substitution! Though, how careful should we be with square root of squares?

Comment: @Mehdi: I believe it is a well-known substitution, so you should not give me credit for it. Where in this are you concerned about the square root of squares?

Comment: I just rechecked and see that this is all flawless. I am not sure what was I unhappy about :-)! (I upvoted it yesterday)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is a lot uglier than it originally looked.  First, let's bring the denominator under the radical.

$$\int\sqrt{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}}dx=\int\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}dx$$.

Now let's make the substitution rlgordonna suggested.

$$x=\tan y,dx=\sec^2ydy$$
$$\int\sqrt{1+\frac1{\tan^2y}}\sec^2ydy=\int\sqrt{1+\cot^2y}\sec^2dy=\int\csc y\sec^2ydy$$

It will take a little work from here to get this to look like something recognizable.

$$\int\csc y(1+\tan^2y)dy=\int\csc ydy+\int\csc y\tan^2ydy$$

I assume you know how to do the first integral.  It's similar to the integral for $\sec y$.  As for the second half

$$\int\csc y\tan^2ydy=\int\frac1{\sin y}\times\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}\times\tan ydy=\int\sec y\tan ydy$$

which should now be in a form that looks familiar.

Comment: Yes, it was quite ugly, but I figured at this level we should avoid suggesting hyperbolics (no offense meant to @Chris'sSister).  It should be pointed out that it is urged that OP check his work by differentiating his result; it is actually nice to see the cancellations involved in getting the original function back.